# Code signing issue after adding support for private API

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, code-signing, provisioning-profile

In my iOS app, I want to use a Private API for which I need to add "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications" key in Entitlements.plist. After I add this key I have started getting code signing errors. Any clue how to tackle this? How do we create a provisioning profile that is signed with correct entitlements?

My Entitlements.plist:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: I think the error saying everything **The entitlements specified in your application's code signing entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile**

Comment: Yeah... That is what my confusion is. While creating the provisioning profile, do we sign it with an Entitlements?

Comment: Yes ... See the option below when you create provisioning profile. There are check boxes which you will have to check according to your requirement. By default they are checked for Game Center and one more box don't remember the name Sorry.

Comment: ok let me check. I hope it would then ask me for Entitlements and then I could sign it with appropriate Entitlements.

Comment: Well there is no way to add a custom entitlements while creating a new provisioning profile.

Comment: Will let you know tomorrow. Need to check it

Comment: Ok thanks... That would be helpful.